# how to go to another page in react native?

Tags: react-native

how to move from one page to another in react native, please help me I am new to react-native I want to move from this page to another by clicking a button but I don't know how to do this

this is splash screen JSON file

```
import React from 'react';

  import { View, Text, Button, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

//import { LinearGradient } from 'react-native-svg';

//import {LinearGradient} from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
//import { LinearGradient } from "react-native-svg";
//import {MaterialIcons} from 'react-native-vector-icons';
  import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

//import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
//import SignInScreen from './SignInScreen';


  const SplashScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Animatable.Image animation="bounceIn" duraton="1500" source= 
   {require('../components/images/roz.jpg')} style={styles.logo} resizeMode='stretch'/>
            </View>
            <Animatable.View animation="fadeInUpBig" style={styles.footer}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Stay connected with everyone!</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Sign in with account</Text>
                <View style={styles.button}> 
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignInScreen')} >
                           <Text style={styles.textSign}>Get Started</Text>
                              
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </Animatable.View>
        </View>
    );
   };

  export default SplashScreen;

  const {height} = Dimensions.get("screen");
  const height_logo = height * 0.28;
```

Comment: I don't know how to move to another page, please someone help

Comment: read this document. https://reactnavigation.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to implement [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) library as described on [official page](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation)

[Navigating to a new screen](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```